# The chat link on HTTPS pages links to global chat rooms, not site specific rooms

Tags: bug, chat, ssl

On HTTPS pages if I click Stack Exchange -> chat it drops me off here (https://chat.stackexchange.com/) with "all" filtering selected. On HTTP pages Stack Exchange -> chat drops me off with "site" filtering, listing the rooms specific to the site I am on.

HTTPS should mirror the behaviour that HTTP pages have. Can this be fixed please? It makes it almost impossible to find chat rooms of a specific site if I don't know their name.

Comment: Maybe when in https, referrer header is not sent so SE can't know where you came from.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is probably the case, but it should be relatively easy to change the chat link to include the site & filtering options in the URL itself, just like on your profile for e.g.

Comment: True, but as it stands even trivial bugs sometimes wait for long years to get official love and attention.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know that all too well :( *looks at list of lonely bugs reported*

Comment: That said and all aside, we should not be using Stack Exchange over https just yet (and that yet might be a loooooooong one), and I do hope that once https is fully supported, they will also change this somewhat-archaic mechanism. (Since referer header isn't very reliable to begin with, and many security programs block it anyway)